# Trocar a posição de uma palavra no texto (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de trocar a posição de uma palavra no interior de um detrminado texto usando javascript.

```html
<form>
  <p> Este é o paragrafo, esta é <strong>palavra</strong> a ser movida </p>
  <span>Troque aqui a posicao da <strong>palavra</strong>no texto : </span>
  <input type="range">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui esta uma versao mais elaborada fazendo uso do `input[type=range]`

```js
document.getElementById('posicao').addEventListener("input", function() {
  var posicao = this.value; //guarda a posicao do input
  var palavra = document.querySelector('p strong').innerText; // busca a palavra que esta no <strong>
  var texto = document.querySelector('p').innerText.replace(palavra, ''); //remove a palavra do texto
  var pos = Math.floor((posicao*texto.length)/100); //define a nova posicao da palavra, quase como a regras dos 3 simples
  document.getElementById('novo_texto').innerHTML=texto.slice(0,pos)+' <strong>'+palavra+'</strong> '+texto.slice(pos); // insere a palavra no texto
});
```

```html
<p> Este é o paragrafo, esta é <strong>palavra</strong> a ser movida </p>
<input type="range" id="posicao">
<p id="novo_texto"></p>
```

**Boa Sorte!**

Comment: Valeu papai !!!

Answer (score 0):

Guarde o texto numa váriavel

```
var txt = "Este é o paragrafo, esta é **palavra** a ser movida"
```

Guarde a palavra numa variável

```
var word = "palavra"
```

Depois de seleccionar a posição`var pos`
Faz:

```
var novotxt=[t.slice(0,pos), word, t.slice(pos)].join(" ")
```

Aqui divide-se o texto em duas partes, e coloca-se a palavra desejada na posição escolhida. Esses "pedaços" de texto ficam no array, e logo faz-se `join()` para compor o `novotxt`